# FIFA 2010 stuttering every 2-3 seconds in game

Tags: fifa-10, ps3

Strangest problem, I bought a used PS3 + FIFA from my brother-in-law, he had FIFA 2010 South Africa working perfectly last time I saw, he has now moved country and I tried booting it up the other day and tonight to play and it glitches in-game (on field) every 2-3 seconds for about 50ms causing a really irritating stutter, cutting the sound and making the game quite unplayable.

Has anyone encountered this before? I really am not sure what's going on or if I have any control on how to fix it, I have ran the latest PS3 system update and the disc looks clean.

Graham

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have a good old stab in the dark and say it's overheating.

Is the machine properly ventilated (not got clothes on top and/or carpet underneath)? Has it been in a dusty environment recently?

I'm not just besmirching the cleanliness of your house; I get the same issue on my laptop when it's on battery and the heat sink is running on low-power.

Comment: Thanks I'll check on the heat when I next can and see if that's it.